# How to reference "this" of another parameter passed into function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, this

Say I have a javascript function for a hover event like this:

```
hoverFunc = function (HoverElement, AnimatedElement) {
    HoverElement.on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            AnimatedElement.hide();
        }
    });
}
```

The tricky part is I want to keep AnimatedElement dynamic, and be able to use it as a reference of HoverElement's "this".

Here's an example of how I'd want AnimatedElement to function:

```
hoverFunc = function (HoverElement, AnimatedElement) {
    HoverElement.on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            $(this).find("img").hide(); //this being a reference to HoverElement
        }
    });
}
```

So I'd like AnimatedElement to be able to be a "this" reference to HoverElement. I've tried writing it like this:

```
hoverFunc($("div"), $(this).find("img"));
```

But obviously the "this" will not reference the first parameter. Is there a way to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: I am not sure whether I understand the question. Do you think that `this` is bound to an object?

Comment: If you want `AnimatedElement` why not say `AnimatedElement`? If don't want it and aren't going to use it, why have it as a parameter at all?

Comment: I'm sorry if my terminology is off. Basically I'd like to be able to reference  "this" instance of a hovered event in a function (this element being passed in by a parameter). Does that make sense?

Comment: if you define the handler inside, it will be able to see `AnimatedElement`, so why fix what's not broke?

Comment: hobbs, I am intending to use. I want to use it as a "this" reference to another parameter passed.

Comment: dandavis, I don't want to define the handler inside, I want it to be dynamic. The second example shows how an exampel of how I want the second passed parameter to function.

Answer (score 2):

instead of `this` use `event.target` and pass `event` in `mouseenter` function call

```
mouseenter: function (event) {
        $(event.target).find("img").hide(); //this being a reference to HoverElement
    }
```

Comment: What if sometimes I don't want to reference $(this).find("img"), I want the animation to be applied to something completely unrelated to the hovered element?

Comment: you can use jquery .closest(). But if you're finding elements REALLY randomly without passing any of their references, well then good luck!

Comment: No, nothing random at all and nothing to do with closest(). I want the animation to be applied to the second parameter I pass. The only caveat is that I would like to be able to reference 'this' instance of the first parameter passed with the second parameter, and sometimes I want the second parameter to just be a normal parameter that you'd pass like usual. See what I mean?

Answer (score 2):

Use `bind()` to do this

```
hoverFunc = function (HoverElement, AnimatedElement) {
HoverElement.on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(this).find("img").hide(); //this being a reference to HoverElement
    }.bind(HoverElement)
});
}
```

[fnc.bind() Description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: This is also how I would do it. In order to improve this answer, it may help to explain why bind works here, and give a link to some documentation for it (such as MDN).

Comment: But now you've hard coded the animated element to always be $(this).find("img"). I'd like to be able to have it be totally dynamic, say sometimes I want it to be a div located outside of HoverElement that has no relation to it, and sometimes I want it to be $(this).find(".other_class").

Comment: Ok, replace `$(this).find("img").hide();` with `AnimatedElement.find("img").hide();` and you'll have a reference on the AnimatedElement

Comment: If I replaced $(this) with AnimatedElement I wouldn't have a reference to 'this' HovererElement.

Answer (score 0):

From your example,

```
hoverFunc = function (HoverElement, AnimatedElement) {
    HoverElement.on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            $(this).find("img").hide(); //this being a reference to HoverElement
        }
    });
}
```

Here `this` withing `mouseenter` event is actually `HoverElement`'s `this`. As you're binding the `mouseenter` on `HoverElement`, so withing event callback `this` is actually `HoverElement`.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qt4gycy7/)**